# Solr: What is the difference between numFound and docfreq

Tags: solr

The `docfreq` function "returns the number of documents that contain the term in the field" as stated in the documentation, and the value `numFound` that is returned with every search, should yield the number of documents matching your search.

But I've not been able to find what the difference between the two are.

For instance, I have a query that yields `"response": { "numFound": 9693, ...` and when I use the `docfreq` function, I get `"docfreq": 9705,` in the same query (that only have a single word).

But why do they differ? I saw a post suggesting that it was "deleted docs", but there are 0 of those, according to the Solr admin interface.

Comment: Try to issue an optimize - that should expunge any deleted docs in the index for good (the count shown in the admin interface might be off). You can also use `debugQuery` to show the `docFreq` used in the score calculation.

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh ! An optimize did the trick!

So, to understand the difference between the two, docfreq seems to include any deleted documents when counting (until an optimize is issued) and the numFound does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MatsLindh suggested in the comment, an optimize aligned `numFound` and `docfreq` to show the same number!
Thanks a lot @MatsLindh.

So it would seem that they do in fact show the same number (namely the number of documents matching the search/term), but `docfreq` seems to include deleted docs (which are purged with an optimize) whereas `numFound` do not.